# Все элементы в строчку. Как сделать

Tags: html, css, form

Здравствуйте. Имею следующий кусочек html кода.

```html
 <div class="row">
        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>${sessionScope.lang['filter_price']}</label>
                <div class="range range-success" style="width: 40%;">
                    <input type="range" name="range" min="${sessionScope.min_price}"
                           max="${sessionScope.max_price}" value="${sessionScope.value_price}"
                           onchange="rangeSuccess.value=value">
                    <output id="rangeSuccess">${sessionScope.value_price}</output>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">${sessionScope.lang['find']}</button>
        </form>
        <form class="form-inline">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
            ${sessionScope.lang['filter_off']}</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Очень интересует вопрос, а как сделать, чтобы все это шло в линию ?
Вроде бы первая форма идет как form-inline, но почему то кнопка всегда идет снизу полоски. 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
form.form-inline > * {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Формы теперь в линию. А как сделать, чтобы range шел в линию с этими кнопками ?